# как мапить результаты native jpa запросов напрямую в DTO?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, dto

Попытка разобраться, как мапить результаты @Query в dto объект

spring-jpa репозиторий

```
@Repository
public interface OperatorRepository extends CrudRepository<OperatorRecord, String> {
    @Query(value = "select org.ORGUNITNAME as orgDivision, op.PYUSERIDENTIFIER as userIdentifier, op.PYUSERNAME as userName from EXTRA_OPERATORS op LEFT JOIN EXTRA.ORGANIZATIONS org ON op.PYORGDIVISION=org.ORGUNITID", nativeQuery = true)
    Iterable<OperatorPojo> aggregateOperators();
```

Пытаюсь смапить результы запроса в dto:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class OperatorPojo {
    String orgDivision;
    String userIdentifier;
    String userName;
}
```

Если мапить просто в Iterable - то все работает нормально.
Что делаю не так, чтобы мапить напрямую в dto - объект?

В случае, когда пытаюсь мапить напрямую в DTO, получаю такую runtime ошибку:

```
ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type
[agregator.OperatorPojo]
```

Пробовал так же и такой вариант с jpql:

```
  @Query(value = "select new agregator.OperatorPojo(org.ORGUNITNAME,op.PYUSERIDENTIFIER, op.PYUSERNAME) from EXTRA.PR_OPERATORS op LEFT JOIN EXTRA.ENT_DATA_SUDIR_ORGUNITEXT org ON op.PYORGDIVISION=org.ORGUNITID")
    Iterable<OperatorPojo> aggregateOperators();
```

Comment: ну так вы массив объектов в объект никак затолкать не сможете)

Comment: @Дмитрий ну, в принципе логично. Видимо ближайший вариант это использовать jpql..

Comment: Попробуйте вместо класса мапить на интерфейс.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб идея хорошая, но словил рантайм ексепш что неверный синтаксис query

Answer (score 2):

1. Отображения таблицы всегда идет только в Entity.
2. DTO - объекты такого назначения являются контейнерами, которые принимают данные от Entity и передают на веб-слой и с веб-слоя данные передаются в DTO, а оттуда в Entity.
3. Между ними всегда есть конвертор, который преобразует из entity в dto и наоборот.
4. Если вы запросили данные, а получаете больше чем одну запись, то вы обязаны использовать тип данных Iterable (это интерфейс).
5. Если вы уверены что у вас одна запись, например запрашиваете строку по уникальному значению, а это значит, что такая запись уникальна в базе, тогда вам не нужно указывать что вы получаете коллекцию записей.
6. Кроме того, для маппинга вы должны использовать одну из библиотек, реализующих стандарт от Oracle - JPA. Наиболее распространенный фраймворк - Hibernate (он построен согласно паттерну ORM).
7. Над полями должны быть указаны аннотация @Column (name= "имя поля") , на  идентификатором указано @Id и тип генарации и стратегия, в зависимости от используемой СУБД.

Хотя я может неверно понял ваш вопрос.